# drupal mutisite

Tags: drupal

we develop two sites in **drupal** both sites have different **urls** and different drupal instance but some pages in the both site have common.

If we edit one page (common) in the both site.we need to login to both sites and edit them.instead of doing like this if edit one site its automatically reflect in particular page in second site.is there any module to provide such functionality or interconnecting two sites.Kindly any one share me how to handle this.

Note :

This sites developed in **drupal 6.x**

Thanks.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Domain Access Module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) does exactly that

Comment: Thanks clive for suggesting module which exactly meet my requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve single sign on by sharing common tables related to user information and same $cookie_domain in the settings.php

Something like following in settings.php:

```
$db_prefix = array(
  'default'   => '',   
  'users'     => 'example_shared_db.',
  'sessions'  => 'example_shared_db.',
  'role'      => 'example_shared_db.',
  'users_roles'      => 'example_shared_db.',
  'profile_fields' => 'example_shared_db.',
  'profile_values' => 'example_shared_db.',
);
```

$cookie_domain = 'example.com';

Answer (score 0):

You have two options 
1. Domain Access module - http://drupal.org/project/domain - This module provide very useful set of feature which will allow you to get your multi-site setup done in lesser time. It has very friendly dashboard to manage your sites. 
2. Folder based structure - you may refer any URL

```
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site
https://www.acquia.com/blog/power-drupal-multi-site-part-1-code-management
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-multisitedrupal/
```

Please let me know in case you looking forward to implement any specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieved this is by using Multi site setup for Drupal. Multi site use the same code base for both the site. You can opt to choose different or same database for your site. For you situation you can use the same database for both the domain.  You can setup a same database for both the site if functionality doens't differs much.